# what is the frame request pending meaning in flutter GPU rendering

Tags: flutter

I found some frame rending take too much time in flutter, now I turn on the devtools perfomance tunning, and find the time mainly take in request frame pending like this:

[image]

what is this meaning and what should I do to make the GPU rending fast?

Comment: I am stuck on the same thing

Comment: I finally found in real device it has no performance issue but in emulator the render is slow, so I suggest you to run it in a real device to check the finnally performance result.@csguy

Comment: Just for future reference, to better profile you should run your app on Profile Mode and on an actual device (emulators are usually slow)